# Manually Set Value for FormBuilder Control

Tags: forms, components, angular

This is driving me nuts, I'm under the gun and can't afford to spend another whole day on this.

I am trying to manually set a control value ('dept') within the component, and it's just not working - even the new value logs to console properly.

Here is the FormBuilder Instance:

```js
initForm() {
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    'name': ['', Validators.required],
    'dept': ['', Validators.required],
    'description': ['', Validators.required],
  });
}
```

This is the event handler that receives the selected dept:

```js
deptSelected(selected: { id: string; text: string }) {
  console.log(selected) // Shows proper selection!
 
  // This is how I am trying to set the value
  this.form.controls['dept'].value = selected.id;
}
```

Now when the form is submitted and I log out `this.form` the field is still blank!  I've seen other ppl use `updateValue()` but this is beta.1 and I don't see that as a valid method to call on the control.

I have also tried to call `updateValueAndValidity()` with no success :(.

I would just use `ngControl="dept"` on the form element, like I'm doing with the rest of the form but its a custom directive/component.

```html
<ng-select
  [data]="dept"
  [multiple]="false"
  [items]="depts"
  (selected)="deptSelected($event)" <!-- This is how the value gets to me -->
  [placeholder]="'No Dept Selected'">
</ng-select>
```

Comment: I had run into similar situation, the scenario was the value was set in http.get-subscribe and load the form value, but setting the value line getting executed first, the subscribe really get executed later as its asynchronous. so setting the value in the subscribe make sure its set. my2cents!

Comment: You can assign ` this.form.controls['dept'].value = selected.id;` because it is a read only property.

Answer (score 531, accepted):

**Updated: 19/03/2017**

```
this.form.controls['dept'].setValue(selected.id);
```

**OLD:**

For now we are forced to do a type cast:

```
(<Control>this.form.controls['dept']).updateValue(selected.id)
```

Not very elegant I agree. Hope this gets improved in future versions.

Comment: This works nicely, thanks.  Also need to clear the validation:  `(<Control>this.form.controls['dept']).setErrors(null)`

Comment: Or yet `this.form.get('dept').setValue(selected.id)` :)

Comment: Just a note. You can also access the property directly without an indexer.
`this.form.controls.dept.setValue(selected.id);`

Comment: but this will not execute validation for the new data!! How to manually trigger change detection after updating?

Comment: It's 2019 for me this works: `this.form.controls['dept'].setValue(selected.id);`

Comment: For the win! YES!

Comment: my code is like this this.addCallForm.get('callerForm').get('callerId').setValue(2);. the value change, but select is not updating.

Comment: I have a question. When do we need to explicitly use `setValue`. 
Shouldn't `this.form` watch for parameters changes and update the form ?

Answer (score 124):

In Angular 2 Final (RC5+) there are new APIs for updating form values. The `patchValue()` API method supports partial form updates, where we only need to specify some of the fields:

```
this.form.patchValue({id: selected.id})
```

There is also the `setValue()` API method that needs an object with all the form fields. If there is a field missing, we will get an error.

Comment: Just to add that as of now `updateValue` (from accepted answer by Filoche) is being deprecated in favour of `setValue`

Comment: Here is the [official pull request](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10537) on Github and the rationale for deprecating `updateValue()` and introducing `patchValue` and `setValue`.

Comment: but this will not execute validation for the new data!! How to manually trigger change detection after updating

Answer (score 43):

If you are using form control then the simplest way to do this:

```
this.FormName.get('ControlName').setValue(value);
```

Answer (score 23):

Aangular 2 final has updated APIs. They have added many methods for this.

To update the form control from controller do this:

```
this.form.controls['dept'].setValue(selected.id);

this.form.controls['dept'].patchValue(selected.id);
```

No need to reset the errors

References

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html

https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-form-controls-patch-value-set-value

Comment: difference between the two - `setValue()` when called on a `formGroup/formBuilder`, it requires all the values under the form to be set.
`patchValue()`, when called on the same, could be used to update specific values.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the following methods to update the value of a reactive form control. Any of the following method will suit for your need.

**Methods using setValue()**

```
this.form.get("dept").setValue(selected.id);
this.form.controls["dept"].setValue(selected.id);
```

**Methods using patchValue()**

```
this.form.get("dept").patchValue(selected.id);
this.form.controls['dept'].patchValue(selected.id);
this.form.patchValue({"dept": selected.id});
```

Last method will loop thorough all the controls in the form so it is not preferred when updating single control

**You can use any of the method inside the event handler**

```
deptSelected(selected: { id: string; text: string }) {
     // any of the above method can be added here
}
```

You can update multiple controls in the form group if required using the

```
this.form.patchValue({"dept": selected.id, "description":"description value"});
```

Answer (score 12):

I know the answer is already given but I want give a bit brief answer how to update value of a form so that other new comers can get a clear idea.

your form structure is so perfect to use it as an example. so, throughout my answer I will denote it as the form.

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    'name': ['', Validators.required],
    'dept': ['', Validators.required],
    'description': ['', Validators.required]
  });
```

so our form is a **FormGroup** type of object that has three **FormControl**.

> There are two ways to update the model value:
>
> - Use the setValue() method to set a new value for an individual control. The setValue() method strictly adheres to the structure of
>     the form group and replaces the entire value for the control.
> - Use the patchValue() method to replace any properties defined in the object that have changed in the form model.
>
> The strict checks of the setValue() method help catch nesting errors
>   in complex forms, while patchValue() fails silently on those errors.
>
> **From Angular official documentation** [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#patching-the-model-value)

so, When updating the value for a form group instance that contains multiple controls, but you may only want to update parts of the model. patchValue() is the one you are looking for.

lets see example. When you use **patchValue()**

```
this.form.patchValue({
    dept: 1 
});
//here we are just updating only dept field and it will work.
```

but when you use **setValue()** you need to update the full model as it strictly adheres the structure of the form group.
so, if we write

```
this.form.setValue({
    dept: 1 
});
// it will throw error.
```

We must pass all the properties of the form group model. like this

```
this.form.setValue({
      name: 'Mr. Bean'
      dept: 1,
      description: 'spome description'
  });
```

but I don't use this style frequently. I prefer using the following approach that helps to keep my code cleaner and more understandable.

What I do is, I declare all the controls as a seperate variable and use setValue() to update that specific control.

for the above form, I will do something like this.

```
get companyIdentifier(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get('name') as FormControl;
}

get dept(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get('dept') as FormControl;
}

get description(): FormControl {
    return this.form.get('description') as FormControl;
}
```

when you need to update the form control just use that property to update it. In the example the questioner tried to update the dept form control when user select an item from the drop down list.

```
deptSelected(selected: { id: string; text: string }) {
  console.log(selected) // Shows proper selection!

  // instead of using this.form.controls['dept'].setValue(selected.id), I prefer the following.

  this.dept.setValue(selected.id); // this.dept is the property that returns the 'dept' FormControl of the form.
}
```

I suggest to have a look [FormGroup API](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) to get know how of all the properties and methods of FormGroup.

**Additional**: to know about **getter** see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)

Answer (score 10):

You could try this:

```
deptSelected(selected: { id: string; text: string }) {
  console.log(selected) // Shows proper selection!

  // This is how I am trying to set the value
  this.form.controls['dept'].updateValue(selected.id);
}
```

For more details, you could have a look at the corresponding JS Doc regarding the second parameter of the `updateValue` method: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/common/forms/model.ts#L269.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - however updateValue doesn't seem to be a valid method in angular2 beta.1  - Which version are you on that you are able to use that method?

Comment: Typescript gives the following error: `error TS2339: Property 'updateValue' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'`.  In that component, the form has the type of `ControlGroup`.

Perhaps if I create them individually with `new Control()` this would work

Answer (score 9):

None of these worked for me. I had to do:

```
  this.myForm.get('myVal').setValue(val);
```

Comment: Same happened with me.
Why is this the case?

Answer (score 5):

```
  let cloneObj = Object.assign({}, this.form.getRawValue(), someClass);
  this.form.complexForm.patchValue(cloneObj);
```

If you don't want manually set each field.

Answer (score 3):

@Filoche's Angular 2 updated solution. Using [`FormControl`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html)

<strike>`(<Control>this.form.controls['dept']).updateValue(selected.id)`</strike>

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

(<FormControl>this.form.controls['dept']).setValue(selected.id));
```

Alternatively you can use  @AngularUniversity's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024326/2013580) which uses `patchValue`

Answer (score -1):

**Tip:** If you're using `setValue` but not providing *every* property on the form you'll get an error:

`Must supply a value for form control with name: 'stateOrProvince'.`

So you may be tempted to use `patchValue`, but this can be dangerous if you're trying to update a whole form. I have an `address` that may not have `stateOrProvince` or `stateCd` depending upon whether it is US or worldwide.

Instead you can update like this - which will use the nulls as defaults:

```
this.form.setValue( { stateOrProvince: null, stateCd: null, ...address } );
```