# How to set value to FormBuilder object in angular 2 Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am used Reactive form Validation(Model driven validation) but cant set the value to form object on Dropdown change

**This is my Formgroup**

```
studentModel:StudenModel
AMform: FormGroup;
Name = new FormControl("", Validators.required);
Address = new FormControl("", Validators.maxLength(16));

constructor(fb: FormBuilder){     
  this.AMform = fb.group({
    "Name": this.Code,
    "Address": this.Abbrev,
  });
}
onAccntChange(event: Event) {
  // set the value from Class Model
  ////  this.studentModel 
  // how to set this.studentModel value to form
}
```

**This is My html page**

```
<form [formGroup]="AMform" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <select (change)="onAccntChange($event)" class="form-control" [disabled]="ddlActivity" formControlName="AccountManagerID">
        <option value="0">Select</option>
        <option *ngFor="let item of allStudent" value={{item.StudentID}}>
            {{item.Name}}
        </option>
    </select>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Name">
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="Name.valid || Code.pristine" class="error"> Name is required </div>

    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="Address">
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="Address.valid || Address.pristine" class="error">Address is required </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning "><i class="fa fa-check-square"></i> Save</button>
</form>
```

On change i need to set the formcontrol value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manually Set Value for FormBuilder Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039610/manually-set-value-for-formbuilder-control)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can achievie that by invoking `setValue` method on your `FormControl` object:

```
  (<FormControl> this.AMform.controls['Name']).setValue("new value");
```

or:

```
this.Name.setValue("new value");
```

Comment: can u pls this one

Comment: Name = new FormControl({ value:'', disabled: true }, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10) ]);

i want to disabled false on change 
can u pls tell me the solution...

Comment: You can also use "as"
`const fc = this.AMform.controls['Name'] as FormControl;
fc.setValue('new value');
`

Answer (score 6):

Use patchValue method of your FormGroup object.

```
 onAccntChange(event: Event) {
    this.AMform.patchValue({yourControl: studentModelValue})
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `setValue` you need to specify **all** the FormControls:

```
this.AMform.setValue({'Name':'val1', 'Address':'val2'})
```

Using `patchValue` you can specify **just the one** you need:

```
this.AMform.patchValue({'Name':'val1'})
```

[Here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#populate-the-form-model-with-setvalue-and-patchvalue) you can read a little bit more.