# Binding to [value] doesn't update FormControl's value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

**More Info:**

I have a list of items. Each item is an instance of a `MyClass`. `MyClass` has a property `text` and a method `someMethod()` that returns this property.

I have an `*ngFor` that lists all items on the page and when I click one of them `(click)="currentItem = item"` is executed and the `[value]="someMethod()"` is actually `[value]="currentItem.someMethod()"`, so the selected item's text is written into the textarea.

---

I'm using Reactive forms and have the following in my template:

```
<textarea formControlName="myTextarea" [value]="someMethod()" ...
```

When the page renders and `someMethod()` outputs a string, I can see that string displaying inside the textarea.

However, the `value` property of the `FormControl` is not updated. Why?

Comment: Try to refer:https://stackoverflow.com/a/35437324/7124761

Comment: Here is the stackblitz code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mzk5e8 Another option is to use patchValue()

Comment: That's right, it answers the question, so I accept it, but you must check out the stackblitz source code to understand

Answer (score 1):

look this link https://coursetro.com/posts/code/108/Angular-5-Interpolation,-Property-Binding-&-Event-Binding-Tutorial#

You can use [(ngModel)] with Reactive forms.

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<input name="fname" formControlName="first" [(ngModel)]="example.first">
<input name="lname" formControlName="last" [(ngModel)]="example.last">
</form>
export class App {
form: FormGroup;
example = { fname: '', lname: ''}
constructor(builder: FormBuilder) {
 this.form = builder.group({ first: '', last:''}) 
}
}
```

Comment: With `[(ngModel)]` it could be done, Angular 6 shows me a deprecated warning however and tells me that I shouldn't use it together with `formControlName`.

Comment: <form [formGroup]="form">
 <input matInput [formControl]="myFormControl"
  formControlName="myFormControlName"
  (input)="object.name = $event.traget.value <- some text" 
  >
</form>

export class App {
form: FormGroup;
object {name}; 
constructor(builder: FormBuilder) {
 this.form = builder.group(
 myFormControlName: [this.object.name, Validators.required]
);
}
}

Comment: You can't use ngModel with reactive form. Use [(value)] instead

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are calling SomeMethod() in [value].

what are you looking for exactly ?

take a look here [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup)