# How to manually set values of nested form in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

So I have a nested form like this:

```
form
    - address
        - city
        - state
        - pincode
    - name
    - phone
```

now I want to set the value of pincode programatically.
How do I set it?
I have checked it for the non nested form and found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039610/manually-set-value-for-formbuilder-control/39024326):
But can't seem to find it for nested forms.

I have tried using dot notation for finding controls.

Comment: Are you using Reactive form or template driven form?

Comment: I'm using reactive form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

> Refer Demo to understand form array

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactiveform-nested-array-eytkzfdata)

Use `index` to get controls of **FormArray**.

```
form.controls.address.controls[i].controls.pincode.setValue('your_pin')
```

Answer (score 2):

use `form.get('controlName')`

```
this.form.get('address').get('pincode').setValue(selected.id);
```