# Need to uncheck all checkboxes, when selecting bottom checkbox, no jquery using Angular 7

Tags: checkbox, angular7

Using Angular 7 and no jquery, I need to have one check box, when clicked, will uncheck all preceding checkboxes in a form group.

in my TS file I have this:

```
 initForm() {
  this.financialSectionSix = this.formBuilder.group({
    medicaidOrSssi: [false],
    snap: [false],
    freeOrReducedPriceLunch: [false],
    tanf: [false],
    wic: [false],
    noneOfTheAbove: [false]
   });
 }
```

In my HTML file i have this:

```
<div [hidden]="selectedSectionGroup.sectionSix" class="tab-pane fade show 
active"
id="{{financialSectionEnum.SECTION_SIX}}" role="tabpanel">
<form [formGroup]="financialSectionSix">

<label class="form-check-label" for="financial1">
  <input required formControlName="medicaidOrSssi" id="medicaidOrSssi" 
    class="form-check-input"
    data-hint="yes" type="checkbox" value="true">
  Medicaid or Supplemental Security Income (SSI)
</label>


<label class="form-check-label" for="cada-form-student-financial- 
  section-6-1-2">
  <input required formControlName="snap" id="snap" class="form-check- 
    input" data-hint="yes" type="checkbox"
     value='true'>
  Food Stamps or Supplemental Nutrition Assistance Program (SNAP)
  </label>

<label class="form-check-label" for="cada-form-student-financial- 
 section-6-1-6">
  <input required formControlName="noneOfTheAbove" id="noneOfTheAbove" 
    class="form-check-input" data-hint="yes" type="checkbox" value='true' 
    id="cada-form-student-financial-section-6-1-6"> None of the Above
  </label>
</form>
</div>
```

The None of the above check box should unselect everything

Comment: you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35039610/manually-set-value-for-formbuilder-control

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for my case.  I need to keep validation for each field in this form group as well as include functionality to uncheck all boxes when selecting the bottom one.  When using ngModel, it does not work without setting [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}".  The form group is not registered and validation does not occur.

Comment: The solution can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044661/uncheck-all-boxes-in-form-group-in-angular-7