# Uncheck all boxes in form group in angular 7

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular7, angular-reactive-forms

I need to have one check box in a form group that `unchecks` all `checkboxes` in the same form group as well as keep my validation.

In my **TS file** i have:

```
 initForm() {
   this.financialSectionSix = this.formBuilder.group({
   medicaidOrSssi: [false],
   snap: [false],
   freeOrReducedPriceLunch: [false],
   tanf: [false],
   wic: [false],
   noneOfTheAbove: [false]
  });
}
```

In my **HTML** I have this:

```
<div [hidden]="selectedSectionGroup.sectionSix" class="tab-pane fade show 
active"
id="{{financialSectionEnum.SECTION_SIX}}" role="tabpanel">
<form [formGroup]="financialSectionSix">

<label class="form-check-label" for="financial1">
  <input required formControlName="medicaidOrSssi" id="medicaidOrSssi" 
    class="form-check-input"
    data-hint="yes" type="checkbox" value="true">
  Medicaid or Supplemental Security Income (SSI)
</label>


<label class="form-check-label" for="form-student-financial- 
  section-6-1-2">
  <input required formControlName="snap" id="snap" class="form-check- 
    input" data-hint="yes" type="checkbox"
     value='true'>
  Food Stamps or Supplemental Nutrition Assistance Program (SNAP)
  </label>

<label class="form-check-label" for="form-student-financial- 
 section-6-1-6">
  <input required formControlName="noneOfTheAbove" id="noneOfTheAbove" 
    class="form-check-input" data-hint="yes" type="checkbox" value='true' 
    id="form-student-financial-section-6-1-6"> None of the Above
  </label>
 </form>
</div>
```

I need the last input field to ONLY `uncheck` all other `checkboxes` in this form group,

I also need to be able to keep my validation as well, using `ngModel` caused issues with that since my form `controls` were not able to be registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the final checkbox as it's own control (not registered to the form group) and just listen to the change event on that checkbox:
E.g:

```
<input required formControlName="noneOfTheAbove" id="noneOfTheAbove" 
class="form-check-input" data-hint="yes" type="checkbox" value='true' 
id="cada-form-student-financial-section-6-1-6" (change)="unselectAll()"> 
None of the Above
```

In your component.ts file:

```
unselectAll() {
   this.form.patchValue({
   medicaidOrSssi: false,
   snap: false,
   freeOrReducedPriceLunch: false, 
   tanf: false,
   wic: false
 });
}
```

Comment: This solution worked out perfectly.  Using your method, I created another one to put into the other checkbox inputs that will uncheck the "none of the above" checkbox if any other boxes are selected.  Thank you very much!